# x-editable bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: datetime, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, x-editable

I can't get x-editable datetimepicker to work. I have recently been working with several other data-types with successful results but can't work out what I'm doing wrong for picking time.

I would like to be able to pick time only. Even when I try and test with date and time it's not working for me.

I'm pretty sure I have included all js files required.

Any help will be appreciated.

See tests here: http://ventrabit.com/test/x-ed-time.php

```
<ul>    
<li>
<a href="#" id="reminder2_time" data-type="datetimepicker" data-format="hh:ii" data-placement="right" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-original-title="Morning Reminder">08:00 am</a>
</li>
</ul>
<script>
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$('#reminder2_time').editable();
</script>
```

**NOTE: I fixed this by using Combodate. Just added the combodate.js and datatype combodate. Very simple compared to datetime and datetimepicker**

Comment: Rather than editing the question to show how you fixed it, please add your own solution as a new answer. This makes it clearer for others that will view this question in the future, and allows your answer to be voted up/down and compared to other answers that may be given. You can even accept your own answer if it's the best one yo get.

Comment: Ok i just did, thanks :)

Comment: I don't use the inline `data-*` attributes but after running into the same problem (was a `text` type rather than `datetime`) but after actually setting the `type` in the initialisation it worked fine (`type: 'datetime'`). Apart from that, make sure the `datetime` picker JS and CSS are included in the page and before the editable plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using combodate which works. Just needed to add combodate.js and data-type="combodate".

Demo: http://ventrabit.com/test/x-ed-time.php

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="reminder1time" data-url="reminder1time.php" data-type="combodate" data-template="HH:mm" data-format="HH:mm" data-viewformat="HH:mm" data-pk="1"  data-original-title="Set Reminder 2">8:55 am</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$('#reminder1time').editable({
});
</script>
```

Still not sure what I was doing wrong before but at least I got a solution to the problem.